# How to use map function with JSON object fetch though an API

Tags: json, reactjs, api, dictionary, object

I fetch data from my api, JSON is :

```
{
    "food": [
        {
            "food": "Not Handle",
            "nb": 49
        },
        {
            "food": "Cooked",
            "nb": 1
        },
        {
            "food": "Raw",
            "nb": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

My data are stored in my state when the component didMount so this.state.food contain my JSON data

I tried to to render it like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Row>
            {this.state.food &&
                this.state.food.map((food) => {
                    return (
                        <div >
                            <Col sm={12} md className="mb-sm-2 mb-0">
                                <div className="text-muted">{food.food} :</div>
                                <strong> {food.nb}</strong>
                            </Col>
                        </div>)
                })}
        </Row>
    )
}
```

CompenentDidMount : (getCall is a custom function to fetch)

```
async componentDidMount () {
const food = await getCall(
    `stats/event/count/food?eventRef=${this.props.eventRef}`,
    this.props.authToken,
    false
  );
  console.log('DATA', food); //  printed my data perfectly
  this.setState({ food: food});
}
```

I think I miss something, because I can't map on this object I get map is not a function, I saw it's only an array ?

expected result is really simple i want to display :

```
Not handle: 49
Cooked: 1
Raw: 1
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, are you sure that the data is fetched ? What do you mean by 'can't map' ? Can you show the `componentDidMount` method ?

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't mention, I got map is not a function, i'm sure I got my data, I printed it with a console.log, I added my componentDidMount as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
async componentDidMount () {
const data = await getCall(
    `stats/event/count/food?eventRef=${this.props.eventRef}`,
    this.props.authToken,
    false
  );
  console.log('DATA', data); //  printed my data perfectly
  this.setState({ food: data.food});
}
```

Assumption : 
`await getCall()` return this exact data :

```
{
    "food": [
        {
            "food": "Not Handle",
            "nb": 49
        },
        {
            "food": "Cooked",
            "nb": 1
        },
        {
            "food": "Raw",
            "nb": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

if this is exactly what is returned from getCall(), then you are getting confused due to wrong variable name. Data is actually a map with one key as food which is the array. So in state you have to actually get the value of food key from data which has map function.

Answer (score 1):

After your api call change the `setState` statement to  `this.setState({ food: food.food});`

What you are getting as response from your api is json. so you are trying to use `map` function on a `json`. `map` function could only be used with `array`.

Comment: thanks for your precision about it, because I tried to map on a json instead on a array, I'll be more focused on it next time !